# is it possible to send notification on facebook from any website

Tags: facebook

I am making a website where i want to integrate facebook in our website .. 
I want to send notification to the user for their activities which are done on my site ..
is it possible to integrate facebook on website

Answer (score 1):

No, App Notifications are only for Apps on facebook.com (Canvas Apps, Page Apps), but not for external websites: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/services/appnotifications

Side note: Notifications are there to inform users about stuff happening on Facebook, you should not abuse Facebook as general notification center for external stuff.